# Generate a random number from a list, not including one of the numbers

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to create a list of sequential integers from 0 to n, then after picking a randon integer from that list, generate another random integer from the same list that doesn't include the integer previously generated.

```
n = 10

a = np.arange(1,n) #Creating my initial list

for b=np.random.choice(a): #Generating my first random number
    c=np.random.choice(np.arange(1,b)) or np.random.choice(np.arange(b+1,n))
```

I know that this won't work because my for loop is pretty iffy. I haven't used python in a long time and I am just starting a project and getting myself back into it is proving to be a little tricky!

Comment: At least, please try to come up with working code without obvious errors. This looks like you expect people to come up with the code themselves. That wouldn't help the project, would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the procedure you are trying to perform is random sampling without replacement.

Let's say you want to pick `k` numbers:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10
k = 3

a = np.arange(1,n) #Creating my initial list

numbers = np.random.choice(a, k, replace=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer:

1) Generate your initial list.

2) Shuffle the list.  If there is no library function to do it, then use the Fisher-Yates shuffle.  Hint: there is a big time saver here.

3) Pick the first number from the shuffled list.  This is your initial number.

4) Pick the second number from the shuffled list.  This is your second number that is both (almost) random and not the same as the first number.

Answer (score 0):

> Help on method sample in module random:
>
> sample(self, population, k) method of random.Random instance
>
> Chooses k unique random elements from a population sequence.
>
> Returns a new list containing elements from the population while
>   leaving the original population unchanged.  The resulting list is
>   in selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random
>   samples.  This allows raffle winners (the sample) to be partitioned
>   into grand prize and second place winners (the subslices).
>
> Members of the population need not be hashable or unique.  If the
>   population contains repeats, then each occurrence is a possible
>   selection in the sample.
>
> To choose a sample in a range of integers, use xrange as an argument.
>   This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling from a
>   large population:   sample(xrange(10000000), 60)

Then to pick `k` random non-repeated numbers in range `[0, n]` you can do this:

```py
import random
result_list = random.sample(xrange(n + 1), k)
```